# Ember CLI http-mock as Addon

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon

I'm using Ember CLI's http-mock feature to mock REST API endpoints, but I'd like to use it in multiple Ember CLI applications.  I thought an addon would be a great solution to this, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Does Ember Addon support http-mock?

Here's what I did.

Created an add on

```
$ ember addon my-http-mock
```

Then I created a simple test endpoint in the addon

```
$ ember g http-mock users
```

After publishing it to my github repository, I imported it into an Ember CLI project like this in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "my-http-mock": "git://github.com/git-username/my-http-mock"
}
```

After npm installing it, I ran my app, but going to `http://localhost:4200/api/users` doesn't go to the API endpoint, and instead tries to load the Ember app.

Is there any way to use http-mock in multiple applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to have your addon implement the `serverMiddleware` and you can add middleware, or routes, to the http-mock running in the consuming ember-cli application.

[Advanced Addon customization in ember-cli docs](http://www.ember-cli.com/#advanced-customization)

That hook get's passed a `config` object that has the express app instance on it at `config.app`. You can then add whatever you'd like to do. If you're using the generated http-mock in the addon, it'd look something like this

```
{
  name: 'my-http-mock',
  serverMiddleware: function(config) {
    // To require ALL mocks from your addon
    var server = require('./server');
    server(config.app);

    // To require individual mocks
    var users = require('./server/mocks/users');
    users(config.app);
  }
}
```

This is untested code but should work. The require all mocks one could possibly conflict in a weird way because it adds the bodyparser middleware and connect-restreamer and it probably already has that included if your app already has those from it's local http-mock. Try it out though! :)

note: This answer is in reference to using ember-cli 0.1.2

Comment: This works perfectly. Even the 'ALL mocks' option works and does not conflict with the local http-mock, although if both the addon and the local http-mock have the same endpoint, the local one will win.  One thing that tripped me up is that the local http-mock will return the API response regardless of what the Accept request header is, while the addon http-mock will not respond if the Accept request header is 'text/html'.  So make sure you don't test the addon API by typing the URL in the browser address bar, b/c it will make you think the addon is not working.

Comment: Glad you figured it out Johnny!